# Converting dataframe with multiple dimensions to raster layer

Tags: r, dataframe, grid, mean, raster

I am creating a `raster layer` for an area with multiple environmental variables. All data formats have usually been netCDF files (`arrays`) containing `lat`, `long`, `date` and the variable in question - in this case `sea_ice_fraction`.

The [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/160TWYonrxARo-TmfdnRT1CEn1De6Q_lK/view?usp=sharing) for sea surface temperature (sst), came in an understandable format, at least from the point of view of trying to make a prediction grid:

```
, , Date = 2019-11-25

         Long
Lat           294.875 295.125 295.375 295.625 295.875 296.125    296.375 296.625 296.875     297.125
  -60.125  2.23000002    2.04    1.83    1.53    1.18    1.00  0.9800000    1.06    1.25  1.40999997
  -60.375  2.06999993    1.79    1.60    1.31    1.09    0.97  1.0000000    1.15    1.30  1.42999995
  -60.625  1.93999994    1.64    1.45    1.28    1.14    1.02  0.9899999    1.03    1.10  1.13000000
```

Each row is one single latitude coordinate (of the resolution of the data), and each column is a longitude coordinate paired with the date.

My goal is to calculate the mean of all the date-values for each coordinate cell. Which in the `array` case is easy:

```
sst.c1 <- apply(sst.c1, c(1,2), mean)
```

Then project to a `Raster` layer

However, the format of the sea ice [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JhRHL31bF56gaYWj2VvBgR6o_JcDYJlJ/view?usp=sharing) is in a dataframe, with 4 columns: `lat`, `long`, `date`, and `sea_ice_fraction`:

```
   time                   lat   lon sea_ice_fraction
   <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 2019-11-25T12:00:00Z -66.1 -65.1            0.580
 2 2019-11-25T12:00:00Z -66.1 -65.1           NA    
 3 2019-11-25T12:00:00Z -66.1 -65.0           NA    
 4 2019-11-25T12:00:00Z -66.1 -65.0           NA    
 5 2019-11-25T12:00:00Z -66.1 -64.9           NA
```

How can I turn this `dataframe` into an `array` similar to the sst data? Or directly into a `raster` finding the `mean` of the values for the dates per cell in the `dataframe`?

Comment: it seems like you made this much more difficult than need be. normally you can create a RasterBrick from a ncdf file, and then do `mean(x)`. In this case you may be able to use rasterFromXYZ

Comment: It has been a very long week of coding, haha. I tried rasterFromXYZ, but got some errors regarding NAs. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do this using dplyr?

The following should work fine:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(lat, lon) %>%
   summarize(sea_ice_fraction = mean(sea_ice_fraction)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

should work fine

Comment: Beautiful - I've been using base syntax for so long now, dplyr was under my nose the entire time. Thanks